# rpy2 zoo unused argument

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I've been recently trying to use rpy2 and import zoo library into python.
however, when I run the following sets of code, I receive the following error

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
r_zoo = importr("zoo")
r_zoo.rollapply(ddf,FUN = r_func.fun1, width = 10, align = "left",by_column = True)
```

> res = super(Function, self).**call**(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
>   rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in FUN(data[posns], ...) : unused
>   argument (by_column = TRUE)

The equivalent r code is

```
rollapply(ddf,FUN = r_func.fun1, width = 10, align = "left",by.column = True)
```

I understand that when we use the importr from rpy2.robjects.packages it automatically converts the `'.'` in Rlang to `'_'` in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to get around that problem:

- Use a `kwargs` dict

  ```
  r_zoo.rollapply(ddf,FUN = r_func.fun1, width = 10, align = "left",**{"by.column":True})
  ```
- Explicitly specify that `by_column` is to be translated to `by.column`

  ```
  from rpy2.robjects.functions import SignatureTranslatedFunction`
  r_zoo.rollapply = SignatureTranslatedFunction(r_zoo.rollapply, init_prm_translate = {'by_column': 'by.column'})
  ```

[Source](http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/robjects_functions.html?highlight=init_prm_translate)